# ReactJs/NextJs Environment variable - fetch without using getServerSideProps()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

- I have **defined env variable** for API base url.
- Unfortunately **on production**, **these variables can be fetched only within getServerSideProps()** method, and I want to avoid that.

Is there any **other solution besides adding NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix**.

Can I store that api base url value on some other place instead of in env variables? In some static files or something?

Comment: Why can't you add the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix?

Comment: Why don't you just create file with a bunch of `const` strings than `export` them, treat them as regular variable if they are not sensitive. Just like how you export helper functions

Comment: @juliomalves are there any disadvantages of using NEXT_PUBLIC_?

Comment: @Yunhai because I need to have different values for diferent environments.

Comment: Disadvantages in terms of what? It's just slightly renaming a variable.

Comment: @juliomalves I mean if that variable is just a base url of the api which I am using in whole application, basically there is no reason of not using it and exposing it in browser with next_public_ prefix?

Comment: If you're making requests to an API on the client-side, the full URLs will always be visible anyway (by simply checking the network tab in dev tools). So having the base URL environment variable exposed to the browser with the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix isn't a concern.

Comment: yep, you are right, thanks @juliomalves

Comment: @juliomalves if that's the case, then just use public, there is no way for you to hide those env variables because you are going to call it directly in your client side, people can inspect the api url via browser.